# SQL joins and group by with 3 separate tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two separate queries here that I need to make into one query, I'll post the queries, then try to explain what I'm trying to do.

```
SELECT Distinct I.ITMCDE, V.VNDRCDE, V.VNAME
  FROM (SELECT RIGHT(Items.[Item Number], 3) as ITMCDE FROM Items) I, 
       (SELECT LEFT(Vendors.[Vendor ID], 3) as VNDRCDE, 
               Vendors.[Vendor Name] as VNAME
          FROM Vendors) V
 WHERE I.ITMCDE = V.VNDRCDE
```

In this first one, I simply match up the vendor code with the item code, to get the vendor name that produces the item.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (Items.[Item Description]), ItemQuantities.[QTY Available],
       Items.[Selling U Of M], Items.[Item Number] 
  FROM ItemQuantities 
 INNER JOIN Items ON ItemQuantities.[Item Number] = Items.[Item Number] 
 WHERE Items.[Item Number] LIKE 'WH%'
   AND Items.[Item Number] NOT LIKE '%RMW'
```

In this second one I'm selecting the item description, quantity available from two separate tables (quantity available is in a different table, match them up using the item number)

As you can see, the only correlation between the three tables is the item number, and not even that in the vendors table. The last three characters of the item number correlate with the first three characters of the vendor id... I did not design this setup. I'm just trying to work with it now.

How do I join these two statements into one single statement that will give me the vendor name, item description, Unit of Measure (Selling U of M), and item quantity where the item description is unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Items.[Item Description], 
       ItemQuantities.[QTY Available],
       Items.[Selling U Of M], 
       Items.[Item Number], 
       V.VNAME
FROM ItemQuantities 
   INNER JOIN Items ON ItemQuantities.[Item Number] = Items.[Item Number] 
   INNER JOIN Vendors ON 
       RIGHT(Items.[Item Number], 3) = LEFT(Vendors.[Vendor ID], 3)
WHERE Items.[Item Number] LIKE 'WH%'
       AND Items.[Item Number] NOT LIKE '%RMW'
```

Comment: Using this and other resources (as I had to make some more modifications) I came up with the following, which suits my needs. Thank you *edit* - I cant answer my own question with the code I used for another 5 hours

Comment: @user2073596 -- np, glad it helped.  best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can join it in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (i.[Item Description]), iq.[QTY Available],
       i.[Selling U Of M], i.[Item Number],
       V.VNDRCDE, V.VNAME
FROM ItemQuantities iq INNER JOIN
     Items i
     ON iq.[Item Number] = i.[Item Number] left outer join
     Vendors v
     on LEFT(v.[Vendor ID], 3) = RIGHT(i.[Item Number], 3) 
WHERE i.[Item Number] LIKE 'WH%' and
      i.[Item Number] NOT LIKE '%RMW'
```

I am not sure if you intend anything special with the parentheses around `i.[Item Description]`.  The `distinct` keyword applies to the entire row.

If you want `distinct` only on the description, then you need to use `group by`.  Something like:

```
SELECT i.[Item Description],
       max(iq.[QTY Available]),
       max(i.[Selling U Of M]), max(i.[Item Number]),
       max(V.VNDRCDE), max(V.VNAME)
FROM ItemQuantities iq INNER JOIN
     Items i
     ON iq.[Item Number] = i.[Item Number] left outer join
     Vendors v
     on LEFT(v.[Vendor ID], 3) = RIGHT(i.[Item Number], 3) 
WHERE i.[Item Number] LIKE 'WH%' and
      i.[Item Number] NOT LIKE '%RMW'
group by i.[Item Description])
```

The `max()` will return the maximum value.  If all are the same, then this is a good way to get an "arbitrary" value.

Comment: I was looking for distinct on only the description.

Answer (score 0):

@sgeddes Thank you.

This is what I came up with

```
SELECT DISTINCT
            Item.ITEMNMBR AS [Item Number], 
            Item.ITEMDESC AS [Item Description], 
            Item.ITMGEDSC AS [Item Category], 
            Item.SELNGUOM AS [Unit of Measure], 
            (SELECT VENDNAME FROM PM00200 WHERE (VENDORID = IV00103.VENDORID)) AS [Vendor Name], 
            (CASE WHEN Quan.QTYONHND > 0 THEN 'In Stock' ELSE 'Out of Stock' END) AS [Stock Status]
FROM       IV00101 AS Item INNER JOIN
                      IV00102 AS Quan ON Item.ITEMNMBR = Quan.ITEMNMBR INNER JOIN
                      IV00103 ON Item.ITEMNMBR = IV00103.ITEMNMBR AND Quan.ITEMNMBR = IV00103.ITEMNMBR
WHERE     (Item.ITEMNMBR LIKE 'WH%') AND (IV00103.VENDORID NOT LIKE '%MIL')
```